# Saving data to sql database via php

Tags: php, mysql

I am saving a forms data into a sql database and it is working great for single items such as the following :

```
<input value="<?php echo isset($item['data1']) ? htmlspecialchars($item['data1']) : ''; ?>" class="form-control">
```

What I would like to do is save an input field that ADDS to the end of current saved data, which would work like this :

```
Data saved 10/1/16:
Hello
Data saved 10/2/16:
World
```

Data called from database would look something like : Hello, World

An added bonus would be able to somehow display Data Like this in a text box such as this to the user :

```
- Hello
- World
- Whats
- Up
```

The "-" should allow a user the ability to delete items from that one input in the sql database, but if all are kept, should of course save as "Hello, World, Whats, Up"
How would this best be done?

Sql Table :
A single table is being used, with $item[data1] filling one column

Comment: I think you can **first run a select query** to fetch current data from database **and then run an update query** to insert new data concatenating with the old one.

Comment: It all depends on how you store the form data in your database. If you are using 1 table, then you will need to do updates, but if you use multiple tables (one for the form records, and separate tables for the fields of the forms) then you could do it by inserting the new values. You should add details about your tables to the question.